# MathQuill: How to capture pasted latex if the latex is wrong?

Tags: javascript, mathquill

I am using mathquill library to convert the latex to equation. If the latex is valid it will call the `edit` handler. But if the pasted latex is invalid, then show the alert message. How to capture the pasted latex if it is wrong.

`mathtext.js`

```
var valid = false;
var mathFieldSpan = document.getElementById('math-field');
latexSpan = document.getElementById('latex');
hiddenSpanArea = document.getElementById('hiddenSpan');
mathField = MQ.MathField(mathFieldSpan, {
  spaceBehavesLikeTab: true,
  handlers: {
    edit: function () {
      latexSpan.textContent = mathField.latex();
      valid = true;
    }
  }
});
window.mathField = mathField;

$(mathFieldSpan).keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 86) { //keycode value for "v"
      if (!valid) { // checks if the pasted value is not valid
        alert("error")
      }
      valid = false;
  }
});
```

`mathtext.html`

```
<span id="math-field"></span>
<span id="latex"></span>
```